# Best way to find is my custom ethernet device is online and what IP it has got for iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, ping

Ideas:
1. Pinging all my subnet ( using simple ping etc )
2. Sending GET to all IP in my subnet? ( may be too slow) waiting for 200 or 404 reply.
Thanx

Comment: Did you have the same problems with me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500734/ios-microchip-ethernet-discoverer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you program your ethernet device to respond to Bonjour (mDNS) requests? That's the preferred discovery mechanism in the OSX/iOS ecosystem. **avahi** is an open-source mDNS daemon you might be able to run if your device runs a UNIX-like OS. You might also be able to find or write an embeddable mDNS server that you could integrate into your server if you're not running an OS as such.

Otherwise, I'd probably go with a custom broadcast UDP packet that the device will respond to. (which is basically what Bonjour/mDNS does, but less general) To send a broadcast UDP packet, open a UDP (datagram) socket and send a packet to the local subnet's broadcast IP. Make the packet contents suitably unique, and get your device to respond, e.g. using an HMAC, to avoid picking up any other devices or daemons which coincidentally answer on the same port.

Comment: No, my device doesn't respond to Bonjour, i think i can't  use it. Is it possible to send a custom UDP packet in iOS? Is it possible to use Netbios?

Comment: Maybe you can find netbios libraries that will work on iOS. I don't know anything about netbios, but I kind of doubt it, especially if it doesn't work over IP. I've updated the answer to be clearer on the UDP solution (which Bonjour uses underneath).

Comment: do u think its good idea to send get request to all the subnet?

Comment: with timeoutInterval like 0.2 seconds or smth?

Comment: You're going to run into trouble with a timeout of .2 seconds if the wifi signal is weak and drops packets. Also, TCP doesn't do broadcasting; what are you going to do if the network is configured as 10.0.0.0/8? Open 16 million HTTP connections? Seriously, this is the kind of thing IP broadcast was made for. Use it.

Comment: i agree, i'll try to find is there any mDNS server for Microchip TCP IP stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure IP networking question.  What you want to do is to send a TCP/IP broadcast message to the network and have you custom device respond to it.  See [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_MessageAddressingandTransmissionMethodsUnicastBroa.htm) for some basic details.